# Get Latest Date from Multiple tables in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have multiple tables and each table has it's own last updated date. My requirement is to get the latest last date for a row.

For example:

[image: table A]

[image: table B]

I need to print the latest updated date among all the tables

[image: Output]

I have written a query , but it is returning only one row

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    dates.Val,
    dates.ID
FROM
    (SELECT  
         A.ID, B.T_LAST_WRITE BDT, A.T_LAST_WRITE ADT
     FROM 
         dbo.A, dbo.B
     WHERE 
         A.ID = B.ID_) dt 
UNPIVOT 
    (Val FOR L IN (ADT, BDT)) AS dates
ORDER BY 
    dates.Val DESC;
```

Can anyone please help?

I tried with the below query but it is returning only 1 record

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    dates.Val,
    dates.ID
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         A.ID, B.T_LAST_WRITE BDT, A.T_LAST_WRITE ADT
     FROM 
         dbo.A, dbo.B
     WHERE 
         A.ID = B.ID_) dt 
UNPIVOT 
    (Val FOR L IN (ADT, BDT)) AS dates
ORDER BY 
    dates.Val DESC;
```

Comment: *"but it is returning only one row"* Why would you expect otherwise? That's what `TOP (1)` does.

Comment: It is returning lot of duplicate records  so I added Top(1)

Comment: Well you also have an ANSI-89 `CROSS JOIN` in there, so yes, that would also be expected. See [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you wanted the latest date for each ID

```
select ID, max(T_LAST_WRITE)
from
(
    select ID, T_LAST_WRITE from TableA
    union all
    select ID, T_LAST_WRITE from TableB
) c
group by ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Squirrel's answer.  However, your posted code can also be made functional with the following changes:

1. Add `GROUP BY dates.ID`
2. Change the select to `SELECT MAX(dates.Val), dates.ID` (also dropping the `TOP 1`)
3. Fix the typo `ID_`.

Here is the updated SQL:

```
SELECT
    MAX(dates.Val),
    dates.ID
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         A.ID, B.T_LAST_WRITE_DT BDT, A.T_LAST_WRITE_DT ADT
     FROM 
         dbo.A, dbo.B
     WHERE 
         A.ID = B.ID
    ) dt 
UNPIVOT 
    (Val FOR L IN (ADT, BDT)) AS dates
GROUP BY
    dates.ID
ORDER BY 
    dates.ID
```

[This db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/P4ClUtdQ) demonstrates both answers.